# Am4Chart - how do i handle the xfield?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, jsx, amcharts

[image]

look, my chart's data exist only day xfiled but i want to be on time xfield too.

```
const getData_FeedMove_Table = async (aniSeq, sdate, edate) => {
    let sql = '---';
    //소 1마리 행동 데이타

    sql = '/feeder/movedataAniSeq/' + aniSeq + ',' + sdate + ',' + edate;
    await request
      .get(sql)
      .then((res) => {
        let i = 0;
        let vdata = [];
        let data = res.data;
        console.log('data', data);
        if (Array.isArray(data)) {
          let sum = 0;
          let prevValue = 0;
          let currentValue = 0;
          data.map((item, i) => {
            currentValue = item.aniFeed;
            if (i > 0) {
              data[i].date.toString().substring(8, 10) !==
              data[i - 1].date.toString().substring(8, 10)
                ? (sum = 0)
                : null;
            }
            sum = sum + item.aniFeed;
            vdata.push({
              value: 0,
              date: item.date,
              aniFeed: item.aniFeed / 1000,
              aniFeedSet: data.length > 0 ? item.aniFeedSet / 1000 : 0,
              sumFeed: sum / 1000,
              disabled: isBulletLabelDisabled(prevValue, currentValue),
              time: item.moveInTimeReal.toString().substring(0, 5),
            });
          });
          prevValue = currentValue;
          aniFeed = 0;
          console.log('vdata', vdata);
          setFeedMove24(vdata);
          setFeedMove(data);
        }

        setIsLoaded1(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        setIsLoaded1(true);
      });
  };
```

this is my chart's data code.
and it's chart code.

```
var dateAxis = chartRef.current.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
    dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
    dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 60;

    // dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey("hour", "HH");
    dateAxis.dateFormats.setKey('hour', 'HH');
    // dateAxis.periodChangeDateFormats.setKey('day', 'MM-dd');
    dateAxis.baseInterval = {
      timeUnit: 'hour',
      count: 1,
    };
    // // Y축을 좌측 우측으로 나누어서 처리
    var valueAxis1 = chartRef.current.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
    valueAxis1.renderer.opposite = false; //좌측
```

how can i display my data on time xfield too?

i tried to change setKey on chart code and change my data code's date.
but it didn't work.